# How can i count duplicated entire values in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to count all the duplicated values in a elasticsearch field using aggregations, but  i just found how to count duplicated words inside the values.  [Elasticsearch Aggs Examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_ordering_by_count_ascending)

This is my aggregation:

```
"aggs": {
        "descriptions": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "original_description",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the result:

```
"aggregations": {
    "descriptions": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 21963155,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "word1",
                "doc_count": 432716
            },
            {
                "key": "word2",
                "doc_count": 336246
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

This is counting the duplicated words, and not the field itself.
Is it possible to count the entire field instead of its words so the results looks like the example below?

```
"aggregations": {
    "descriptions": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 21963155,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "entire description 1",
                "doc_count": 432716
            },
            {
                "key": "different description 2",
                "doc_count": 336246
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the mapping for the "original_description" field:

```
"original_description": {
    "analyzer": "lapidar"
    "fielddata": true,
    "type": "text"
}
```

The "lapidar" analyzer uses a bunch of regex replaces, and stemmers, asciifolding and lowercase:

```
"filter": [
        "asciifolding",
        "lowercase",
        "hunspell_pt_BR",
        "portuguese_stemmer"
    ]
```

The stemmers configurations:

```
    "hunspell_pt_BR": {
        "locale": "pt_BR",
        "type": "hunspell"
    },
    "portuguese_stemmer": {
        "language": "portuguese",
        "type": "stemmer"
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the `original_description` field?